# complex PQSQl query in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a pgsql db query in python and execute it from python. I am facing issue in creating that query.

i need to create a **query** like this

```
"select datetime, ask, bid, high, low, close from dashboard_forex WHERE symbol = 'EUR/USD'"
```

so i did like this

```
symbol = "EUR/USD"
"select datetime, ask, bid, high, low, close from dashboard_forex WHERE symbol = '"+symbol+"'"
```

and **worked**!!!

but now i want to create a query like this..

```
"select datetime, ask, bid, high, low, close from public."TFX" WHERE symbol = 'EUR/USD'"
```

i need to get it as string.  I tried many way but nothing helped me. i need to pass this string in another function. here this query will be dynamic, i cant do it manually.
**can anyone help me.** ???

**edit-1** - added actual image of db query.
[image]

here both single and double quotes involved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `str.format()` method

```
tb1 = r'TFX'
sym = r'EUR/USD'
query = """select datetime, ask, bid, high, low, close from public."{}" WHERE symbol = '{}' """.format(tb1, sym)

print(query)
```

output

```
select datetime, ask, bid, high, low, close from public."TFX" WHERE symbol = 'EUR/USD'
```

Comment: but symbol should be in single quotes

Comment: @Sarath_Mj check new solution